# The content in DrawerLayout beyond the scope of screen

Tags: android, material-design

I use CoordinatorLayout,AppBarLayout and Toolbar in a DrawerLayout.But it has lots of problem.

when I use AndroidStudio design ,I saw content_main beyond scrope of screen.
beyondScreenPic.

[image]

And when I run app,it looks like this(Fab shows half):

[see the fab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK9PK.jpg)

Main Activity layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="false">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

this is content_main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and this is some gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh,I solved it by lots of attemption.

> CoordinatorLayout is a super FrameLayout.

So,it will work perfect when just has only one subelement;
Simply use a LinearLayout surround appbarLayout and content_layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="false">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Coordinator Layout height to match parent.
may be it will solve the issue.